# Set master mode on a realtek rtl8192ce

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, realtek, hostapd

The supported interfaces of the network adapter include also AP. But when I try to set the card on Master Mode with `iwconfig wlan0 mode Master`, I get the following error:

> Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted

Is it still possible with `hostapd`? I tried to make it run with `hostapd`, but still no success. Any suggestions? I am trying to do this on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please use the newer `iw` over the older `iwconfig`. Here is a similar issue posted in the Debian Bug tracker for changing ad-hoc mode, but I believe this applies to your master mode case as well: [Debian bug #645055](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=645055)